# DPDK Event Dev Queue Enqueue failure observed

Tags: multithreading, intel, packet, dpdk, dpdk-pmd

During posting packets from one thread to another thread(both threads are in different cores), used DPDK Event Dev Queue.

Observed Event Dev Queue Enqueue failure. Cross checked the EvtDevQ stats, it shown packets are in Inflight mode, not posted to Queue it seems and enqueue failed and not recovered.
Also schedule calls happend multiple times.

**Note:** Receiver thread is not in tight loop

Event Enqueue function:
`rte_event_enqueue_burst()`

Schedule call function:
`rte_service_run_iter_on_app_lcore()`

**Port 0 and Queue 0** Used in this case.

How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

**Stats:**

```
Dev=0 Port=1EventDev todo-fix-name: ports 4, qids 3
     rx   32768
     drop 0
     tx   4096
     sched calls: 628945658
     sched cq/qid call: 628964843
     sched no IQ enq: 628926401
     sched no CQ enq: 628942982
     inflight 32768, credits: 0
   Port 0
     rx   0  drop 0  tx   4096   ^[[0minflight 4096^[[0m
     Max New: 32768  Avg cycles PP: 0    Credits: 0
     Receive burst distribution:
         0:100% 1-4:0.00% 5-8:0.00% 9-12:0.00%
     ^[[0mrx ring used:    0 free: 4096^[[0m
     ^[[0mcq ring used:    0 free:  128^[[0m
   Port 1
     rx   0  drop 0  tx   0  ^[[0minflight 0^[[0m
     Max New: 32768  Avg cycles PP: 0    Credits: 0
     Receive burst distribution:
         0:100%
     ^[[0mrx ring used:    0 free: 4096^[[0m
     ^[[0mcq ring used:    0 free:  128^[[0m
   Port 2
     rx   32768  drop 0  tx   0  ^[[0minflight 0^[[0m
     Max New: 32768  Avg cycles PP: 0    Credits: 0
     Receive burst distribution:
         0:-nan%
     ^[[0mrx ring used:    0 free: 4096^[[0m
     ^[[0mcq ring used:    0 free:  128^[[0m
   Port 3  (SingleCons)
     rx   0  drop 0  tx   0  ^[[0minflight 0^[[0m
     Max New: 32768  Avg cycles PP: 0    Credits: 0
     Receive burst distribution:
         0:-nan%
     ^[[0mrx ring used:    0 free: 4096^[[0m
     ^[[0mcq ring used:    0 free:  128^[[0m
   Queue 0 (Atomic)
     rx   32768  drop 0  tx   4096
     Per Port Stats:
       Port 0: Pkts: 4096    Flows: 1
       Port 1: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 2: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 3: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
     ^[[0miq 0: Used 28672^[[0m
   Queue 1 (Atomic)
     rx   0  drop 0  tx   0
     Per Port Stats:
       Port 0: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 1: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 2: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 3: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
     -- iqs empty --
   Queue 2 (Directed)
     rx   0  drop 0  tx   0
     Per Port Stats:
       Port 0: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 1: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 2: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
       Port 3: Pkts: 0   Flows: 0
     -- iqs empty --
```